# Change background image dimensions according to the maximum between height and width

Tags: css

I have a slider that displays a set if images with different dimensions. For some of them the width is much more bigger than the height, for some of them the height is much more bigger than the width and for some of them height and width are almost the same.

The images are displayed as a background of a `li` tag inside a `ul` list.

```
<ul class="gallery_container">
    <li style="background:url(link1) no-repeat;"></li>
    <li style="background:url(link2) no-repeat;"></li>
    <li style="background:url(link3) no-repeat;"></li>
    <li style="background:url(link4) no-repeat;"></li>
</ul>
```

With css

```
.gallery_container {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.gallery_container li {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    background-position: center !important;
}
```

I want to display the images in a way such that

1. The background image is displayed in the center; ie. if the width or height of the background image is less than the `ul`'s width or height, it must be in the center of the `ul`.
2. The background image does not go out of it's container; ie. the `ul` border. Even if the image's width or height is larger the containre's, the image must not go out of the `ul`'s border.
3. The ratio between the height and width must be constant; any increasing in the height must come with increasing in width with the same ratio of the original dimensions.
4. If The background image's width is bigger than it's height, it's width must be `100%`
5. If The background image's height is bigger than it's width, it's height must be `100%`

### Things I tried to do

- To center the background image I used `background-position: center !important;`.
- I tried to use `background-size: cover;` but it didn't work as I wanted, Images were scratched horizontally and vertically to `100%`, and I want to save the ratio between the height and width.
- I tried to set `background-size: auto 100%` but this does not solve the fourth requirement; if width is bigger than the height it's width won't be `100%`, only it's height in all cases will be `100%`.
- I tried to set `background-size: 100% auto` but this does not solve the fifth requirement; if height is bigger than the width it's height won't be `100%`, only it's width in all cases will be `100%`.

### My question

What should I modify to make the background image's width `100%` when it's width is larger than the height and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wanting to use [`background-size: contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Syntax) Which will maximize the image to the largest side, and maintain aspect ratio.

background-size: **contain**

> A keyword that scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). Image is letterboxed within the container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the empty areas (either top/bottom of left/right) are filled with the background-color.  The image is automatically centered unless over-ridden by another property such as background-position.

Answer (score 0):

If its not the issue that if the user sees the background of the div or ul where image doesn't reach then you could go for `background-size:contain;`

This would save the aspect ratio of background image and you can center it by `background-position:center` and `background-repeat:no-repeat`

This shall solve your problem.